# Cannot invoke 'value' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: swift, swift3, migration

I am a beginner at Swift and I am migrating an app to Swift 3.0

I keep having this error and I have no idea how to solve it.

"Cannot invoke 'value' with an argument list of type '(String)'"

It is displayed at nearly each line of this snippet. 
Do you have any idea where it could come from? 
Thanks a lot

```
        if ((message as AnyObject).value("content") != nil){
            stringContent  = (message as AnyObject).value("content") as? String
        }

        if ((message as AnyObject).value("sender_uuid") != nil){
            stringSenderUuid  = (message as AnyObject).value("sender_uuid") as? String
        }

        if ((message as AnyObject).value("recipient_uuid") != nil){
            stringRecipientUuid  = (message as AnyObject).value("recipient_uuid") as! String
        }

        if ((message as AnyObject).value("date") != nil){

            if let result_number = (message as AnyObject).value("date") as? NSNumber
            {
                stringDate = "\(result_number)"
            }
            else   {

                stringDate  = (message as AnyObject).value("date") as! String

            }

        }
```

As requested here is more information about Messages

```
class Messages: Object {

dynamic var channel_name = ""
dynamic var content = ""
dynamic var sender_uuid = ""
dynamic var recipient_uuid = ""
dynamic var date = ""
dynamic var message_uuid = ""


override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "message_uuid"
}    }



    let message = Messages()
    message.channel_name=channel_name
    message.content=stringContent
    message.sender_uuid = stringSenderUuid
    message.recipient_uuid = stringRecipientUuid
    message.date = stringDate
    message.message_uuid = stringUuid
```

Here is even more information

```
        // initialize with nothing
    var stringContent = " "
    var stringSenderUuid = " "
    var stringRecipientUuid = " "
    var stringDate = " "
    var stringUuid = " "


    // We check for existence in the dictionnary
    if (message["content"] != nil){
         stringContent  = message["content"] as! String
    }

    if (message["sender_uuid"] != nil){
         stringSenderUuid  = message["sender_uuid"] as! String
    }

    if (message["recipient_uuid"] != nil){
         stringRecipientUuid  = message["recipient_uuid"] as! String
    }

    if (message["date"] != nil){
        if let result_number = message.value(forKey: "date") as? NSNumber
        {
            stringDate = "\(result_number)"
        }
        else   {

            stringDate  = message.value(forKey: "date") as! String

        }
    }
    if (message["uuid"] != nil){
         stringUuid  = message["uuid"] as! String
    }
```

Comment: What's `message` and why are you casting it to `AnyObject`?

Comment: I gave more information about messages. I am not sure why it is casted as Anyobject :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to change them to `(message as AnyObject).value(forKey:"···")` (adding the `forKey:` label).

Do you know what kind of object `message` is supposed to be? Repeatedly casting it to `AnyObject` is odd. It would be cleaner to create a new variable - `let messageObject = message as AnyObject` and then call `messageObject.value(forKey:"···")`. (I suspect you really want to cast it to `Dictionary` or something like that, in which case you can do `messageDictionary["···"]` instead of calling `value(forKey:)`.)

Also, in Swift you can do this to reduce redundancy even more:

```
if let content = messageObject.value(forKey:"content") as? String {
  stringContent = content
}
```

Comment: Adding "forKey" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If `message` is json dictionary then cast it to `[String:Any]` and then use subscript with it.

```
if let dic = message as? [String:Any] {
    stringContent = dic["content"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

**OR**

If `message` is type of `Messages` then you can access its property directly using `message.content` and same way you can access other properties too.

```
stringContent = message.content
```

Comment: When I try 
            if ((message.content != nil){
                stringContent  = ((message as AnyObject).value(forKey:"content") as? String)!
            }
it says 

Value of type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member ‘content'

and proposes to change to 
if (((message as AnyObject).content != nil)

Comment: @QuentinDel You need to show how you are getting value in `message` means how you have initialized the `message` that will give us idea.

Comment: I have updated my post with more information about message. The issue is fixed now but I am always eager to learn how to write better code. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @QuentinDel You still don't get it what I have ask is the var `message` that you have used here `(message as AnyObject).value("content") != nil)`. I'm asking about that message variable How you have initailized it you haven't add that code. If it is dictionary then subscript will work no need to type cast it to Anyobject and no need to use `valueForKey`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error in testing (*e.g.* using `LLReactiveMatchers's` `sendValues()`), try to make your type (struct/class) conform to `Equatable`.